# Word Headers / Footers Not Displaying

Tags: vb.net, header, ms-word, footer, visible

I have a ReportViewer that generates a word document. The program then opens the word document for the user to view it. My issue is when I open it using code, the headers and footers do not display.

---

### Manually Opening Word Doc

Header / Footer display fine
[image: Header and Footer appear]

### Code Opening Word Doc

There is no visible headers / Footers here, but when I go to add one, the appear...
[image: No Header and Footer]

I use the following  code to open my word document:

```
Private MSWord As New Word.Application
Private WordDoc As New Word.Document

Private Sub OpenWordFullScreen(ByVal ReportName As String)
    Dim FolderPath As String = "C:\"

    WordDoc = MSWord.Documents.Open(FolderPath & "\" & ReportName & ".doc")
    MSWord.WindowState = Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMaximize
    MSWord.Visible = True
End Sub
```

How can I make the header and footers visible?

Comment: After further investigation, I found that my document is stuck in "Rough" draft instead of "Page". I saw this on the Display tab... If I figure out how to change it I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following code after setting my `MSWord` to visible

```
MSWord.ActiveWindow.View.Type = Word.WdViewType.wdReadingView
```

Enabled me to view the header and footers as well as view the whole thing in FullScreen.